# What is the origin of the German "n-Deklination"?

Tags: history, declension, weak-declension

Being completely unfamiliar with the answer, I would dare say that it is a legacy of Latin, although I fail to recognize any similarity between Latin declensions and this sort of noun alteration. Is there any source that explores the history of this interesting phenomenon?

To quote @Fabio Turati and his nice description of what I mean by "n-Deklination":

> In German you normally decline articles, adjectives and pronouns, but not nouns. Still, some nouns must be declined: in accusative, genitive and dative you have to add an 'n', and these words are said to belong to the "n-Deklination". They are also called "schwache Nomen" (that is, "weak nouns"). For example, let's take "der Name": you say "Wie ist dein Name?" (nominative), but "Sag mir deinen Name**n**!" (accusative).

Comment: This sounds interesting. I wish I knew what the `n-Deklination` is

Comment: @Mawg In German you normally decline articles, adjectives and pronouns, but not nouns. Still, some nouns must be declined: in accusative, genitive and dative you have to add an 'n', and these words are said to belong to the "[n-Deklination](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/n-deklination.html)". They are also called "schwache Nomen" (that is, "weak nouns"). For example, let's take "der Name": you say "Wie ist dein Name?" (nominative), but "Sag mir deinen Name**n**!" (accusative).

Comment: Thank you @Mawg for pointing that out, I thought the nomenclature was universal. I will edit my question to clear things up.

Comment: I understand it, just was not familiar with the term.

Answer (score 10):

The n-Deklination originates from the Indo-European (athematic) n-stems. You may want to take a look at the Wikipedia page about [Proto-Indo-European nominals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals)

It does not originate from Latin; rather, both Latin and Germanic inherited n-stems from Indo-European.

Answer (score 6):

It's a legacy of Proto-Germanis language (and since German is not a descendant of the Latin language, n-Declination cannot be a legacy of Latin). This "n" was a part of a word stem and the n-Form is often the original form of the word. Later, the ending "n" was dropped off in nominative but remained in other cases. *([source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Schwache_und_gemischte_Deklination), in German)*

Comment: Virus and Museum do not have an /n/ in any of its cases in Latin. German cannot "retain" something that never existed.

Comment: @fdb  I removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened "Consonant and vowel gradation in the Proto-Germanic n-stems" before reading this question.

[Todo: Read and summarize 100 odd pages, the bulk making lexical entries]